# How to make sure use one IP access Internet firstly, when a Windows Server have multi IP addresses?

Tags: windows, ip

windows have multi IP addresses, but now I want to browser Internet, I only want to use one IP access Internet preferentially.

such as I have IP addresses:

```
45.1.1.1
45.1.1.2
45.1.1.3
45.1.1.4
```

I want to access the `IP.cn`, I only want to there shows 45.1.1.1, but it(ip.cn) will show 45.1.1.2 or others actually.

how to realize it?

---

**EDIT-01**

I don't know the `skip as source`, is it mean this button? do you mean check it to add secondary IP or uncheck to add 2rd IP?

[image]

Comment: Only one address (45.1.1.1 in shown case) will be used for outbond internet connections. *but it will show 45.1.1.2* Who is this "it"?

Comment: check my post now.

Comment: Check your ipconfig, what address is set as first/primary?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Delete and re-add the secondary addresses with the ["skip as source"](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/rmilne/2012/02/08/fine-grained-control-when-registering-multiple-ip-addresses-on-a-network-card/) flag specified. This can be done through command-line tools only (but *not* through the "TCP/IP Properties" GUI).

**Netsh**

Netsh requires the address to be deleted first, then re-added:

```
netsh interface ipv4 add address <interface> <address>/<prefixlen> skipassource=true
```

For example:

```
netsh int ipv4 add addr "Ethernet" 192.168.1.5/24 skipassource=true
```

**PowerShell**

To add a new address:

```
New-NetIPAddress -IPAddress <addr>/<len> -InterfaceAlias <interface> -SkipAsSource $True
```

PowerShell also allows changing existing addresses:

```
Get-NetIPAddress <address> | Set-NetIPAddress -SkipAsSource $True
```

**Final note**

Note that in Server 2012, you [must use *only* command-line tools](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/rmilne/2012/02/08/fine-grained-control-when-registering-multiple-ip-addresses-on-a-network-card/), as any address change done through the "TCP/IP Properties" GUI will lose this flag for all addresses.

---

Further information:

- Microsoft TechNet Blogs: [Fine Grained Control When Registering Multiple IP Addresses On a Network Card](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/rmilne/2012/02/08/fine-grained-control-when-registering-multiple-ip-addresses-on-a-network-card/) and [Part 2: PowerShell](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/rmilne/2012/11/30/fine-grained-control-when-registering-multiple-ip-addressespart-deux/)
- https://somoit.net/windows/windows-add-secondary-ip-addresses-to-interface
- https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/rmilne/2013/08/27/skipassource-flag-cleared-in-windows-2012/

Comment: is this works for Windows and Linux?

Comment: what's the `skip as source` flag? where is it?

Comment: See `netsh interface ipv4 add address ?`.

Comment: I mean what's the  `with the "skip as source" flag specified.`?

Comment: I edited my post, check it.

Comment: The option can only be specified when using the command-line `netsh` tool. It cannot be changed from the graphical "TCP/IP properties" dialog.

Comment: what's the meaning of `<len>` there? does it mean the prefix? such as 24

Comment: Yes, it means the prefix length in bits.